# Possible bug with displaying birthday text before adding birthday on Profile Page

Tags: bug, profile-page

If you don't have your birthday set in your Stack Exchange profile, then currently the following is displayed:

[image]

Seems like there is a UI issue on Firefox 42.0 where that field's description is cut-off.

Comment: Yeah, the placeholder text is also cutoff for Chrome 47.